# How do I mock a component in my django application that reaches to an external service?

Tags: python, django, testing, mocking

I have a method that reaches out to an external API and pulls in some content, then it performs some logic and proceeds. The problem is, while testing, I don't want my test cases to trigger this external API but I do want it to mock the response. Example

```
def create_animals(candidate):
    if ExternalService.get_candidate_validity(candidate):
         print('Things are good, go ahead')
         #creates the animal objects etc....
```

But `ExternalService.get_candidate_validity` reaches out to an API that I want to mock. I know I can mock instances if it's like this:

```
get_candidate_validity_value = {'response': True}
c = ExternalService('someparamsthatineed')
c.get_candidate_validity = MagicMock(return_value=get_candidate_validity_value)
```

But how do I handle cases where the class is instantiated in a method that I end up calling to test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had a python module `animals.py` that had this:

```
def create_animals(candidate):
    if ExternalService.get_candidate_validity(candidate):
         print('Things are good, go ahead')
         #creates the animal objects etc....
```

You would mock it out this way in `test_animals.py`

```
from mock import MagicMock  # or import mock from stdlib unittest in python 3

def test_create_animals():
    from path.to.animals import ExternalService, create_animals
    ExternalService.get_candidate_validity = MagicMock(return_value=True)
    animals = create_animals('foo')
    ExternalService.get_candidate_validity.assert_called_with('foo')
```

It is a best practice in unit testing to mock out all external services somehow so you're testing the unit, ie the function being tested, and nothing else.

Another way to do this is to use the `patch` functionality in the standard unit testing library.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#attaching-mocks-as-attributes

```
>>> with patch('animals.ExternalService') as MockClass:
...     MockClass.get_candidate_validity.return_value = 'foo'
```